# Is there any intuition for why bisecting an angle gives the optimal angle to throw a ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile

Let's say that I am holding a ball and have zero height, and there is a wall with a height of $h$ that is a distance $d$ away. At what angle should I throw the ball such that getting it over the wall requires minimal speed?

We can actually derive this using calculus. Obviously, the lowest speed that would clear the wall for a given angle would barely clear the wall. If the ball is thrown at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical and just barely clears the wall, then it has fallen by $d \cot\theta - h$ from a straight-line path by the time it clears the wall. The time it takes to fall this much is ${\sqrt\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}.$ In this time, if the ball was thrown at speed $v,$ then it would travel a distance of $d$ horizontally, which is equal to $v \sin\theta{\sqrt\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}.$  Therefore, $d = v \sin\theta{\sqrt\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}.$ Solving for $v$ gives that $v = \frac{d}{\sin\theta{\sqrt\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}}.$ We want to minimize $v,$ so we want to maximize the denominator, which is $\sin\theta{\sqrt\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}$. Therefore, we are attempting to maximize its square, which is  $\sin^2\theta{\frac{2d \cot\theta - 2h}{g}}.$ We can factor out positive constants from the expression since we are trying to maximize it to get that we have to maximize $\sin^2\theta(d \cot\theta - h),$ which is $d\sin^2\theta \cot\theta -  h \sin^2 \theta  = d\sin\theta \cos\theta -  h\sin^2 \theta.$ We can write this in terms of $2\theta$ as $\frac{d}{2}\sin(2\theta) -  \frac{h}{2}(1 - \cos(2\theta)).$ Again, we can remove the factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ and get $d\sin(2\theta) -  h(1 - \cos(2\theta)),$ which we are trying to maximize. Expanding this out gives $d\sin(2\theta) -  h + h\cos(2\theta)).$ Again, since we are trying to maximize this, we can remove the $-h$ term, giving us $d\sin(2\theta) + h\cos(2\theta).$ Differentiating and setting this equal to $0$ gives $d\cos(2\theta) - h\sin(2\theta) = 0.$ Dividing through by $\cos(2\theta)$ gives $d - h\tan(2\theta) = 0.$ Therefore, $h\tan(2\theta) = d,$ so $\tan(2\theta) = \frac{d}{h}.$ If $\alpha$ is the angle that points straight at the top of the wall, then $\theta$ is exactly half of $\alpha.$ Is there any intuitive proof for why the optimal angle to throw a ball is exactly half of the angle from the vertical that points straight at the top of the wall?

Comment: See Relation between horizontal range and maximum height in this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion,   with your notation...:$\frac{h_{max}}{d_{max}}$

Comment: What is “ clearing the wall ” ?

Comment: I edited to clarify the meaning.

Comment: What would you expect an "intuitive" answer to look like? Every answer that derives the angle of one half is going to have to involve math and every answer is going to have to start from your opening mathematical premises. So... I'm not even sure what you are looking for when you say "intuitive proof." Could your explain further?

Comment: Basically, I mean a good reason why it should be about halfway between the vertical and the angle straight at the top of the wall, like the intuition that the optimal way to turn a bolt is to apply force perpendicular to the wrench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting with

$$x=v\,\cos(\theta)\,t\\
y=v\,\sin(\theta)\,t-g\frac{t^2}{2}$$

solve those equations for $~t~,y~$ you obtain

$$y(x,v,\theta)={\frac {x{v}^{2}\sin \left( 2\,\theta  \right) -g{x}^{2}}{{v}^{2}\cos
 \left( 2\,\theta  \right) +{v}^{2}}}
$$
$$t={\frac {x}{v\cos \left( \theta  \right) }}=t_l$$

from here with

$$y(x=d,v,\theta)=h\quad \Rightarrow\quad~\text{initial velocity } \\
v^2=-\frac 12\,{\frac {g{d}^{2}}{ \left( \cos \left( \theta \right) h-d\sin
 \left( \theta  \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta  \right) }}
=v_I^2$$

the velocity "that hit the wall"  is
$$v_w=\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}\bigg|_{\left(v=v_I~,t=\frac{d}{v_I\,\cos(\theta)}\right)}\\
v_w=\sqrt{-\frac 12\,{\frac {g \left( -4\,\sin \left( \theta \right) dh\cos \left( 
\theta \right) +{d}^{2}+4\, \left( \cos \left( \theta \right) 
 \right) ^{2}{h}^{2} \right) }{\cos \left( \theta \right)  \left( \cos
 \left( \theta \right) h-d\sin \left( \theta \right)  \right) }}
}$$

[image]

the velocity  $~v_w~$  is minimum at

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\,v_w=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\theta_m=\arctan\left({\frac {h+\sqrt {{d}^{2}+{h}^{2}}}{d}}\right)\quad\Rightarrow~\text{the initial velocity}\\
v_I^2={\frac {g \left( {d}^{2}+{h}^{2}+h\sqrt {{d}^{2}+{h}^{2}} \right) }{
\sqrt {{d}^{2}+{h}^{2}}}}
$$

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as an intuitive proof.

Comment: In fact, I'd say it's even messier than my calculation.

Comment: @mathlander this is quit starte forwards.  did you got my result ?

Comment: Okay, maybe, but it is very far from being "intuitive."

Comment: @mathlander you know now the right solution, so how you can obtain it "intuitive" ?.  I tried but i don't have the solution .